# Extension of primitive set of vectors and reduction theory

Tags: reference-request, lattices, geometry-of-numbers

Let $\Lambda$ be a unimodular lattice in $\mathbb R^d$ (unimodularity is not really necessary here but just for convenience) and let $B$ be a ball centered at the origin that contains $(k+1)$-many $\mathbb R$-linearly independent vectors in $\Lambda$ ($k<d$).

Suppose $v_1,\dots,v_k$ are a set of linearly independent vectors in $\Lambda \cap B$ that can be extended to a basis of $\Lambda$ (called a primitive set in some literature). I wonder if it is always possible to find a primitive vector $v_{k+1} \in \Lambda \cap B$ (not a proper integer multiple of a shorter vector in the lattice), linearly independent of previous $k$ vectors, such that $v_1,\dots,v_{k+1}$ are again extendable to a basis of $\Lambda$.

I believe there should be some sort of Minkowski's reduction theory being used here but I can't find any good reference addressing this particular problem. Even the case when $k=1$ seems quite non-trivial to me.

---

Update: As is shown in Martin's comment, this may not be true. But I think a weaker version may be true although I don't know how to prove it---instead of finding $v_{k+1}$ in $\Lambda \cap B$, we can find $v_{k+1}$ in some $\Lambda \cap c_d B$ where $c_d B$ is a dilation of $B$ by a factor $c_d$ that only depends on the dimension $d$ such that $v_1\cdots v_{k+1}$ are extendable to a basis of $\Lambda$.

Comment: This is not the case if you drop the assumption of unimodularity. Let $d=5$, $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}^5 \oplus \mathbb{Z}^5 + (1/2,\ldots,1/2)$, where $\mathbb{Z}^5$ is the 5-dimensional cubic lattice. Then the unit ball $B$ satisfies the assumption in the question for $k=4$, since it contains the five unit vectors of $\mathbb{Z}^5$. But it does not contain a basis of   $\Lambda$.

Comment: @MartinSeysen sorry I am confused about your direct sum notation... Is your lattice of rank 5?

Comment: It just means; take the ordinary five-dimensional  cubic lattice and add the centers of all five-dimensional cubes. This lattice  has a basis e.g.  $(1,0,0,0,0)$,   $(0,1,0,0,0)$,  $(0, 0,1,0,0)$,  $(0,0,0,1,0)$,  $(1/2, \ldots, 1/2)$ in standard Euclidean coordinates.

Comment: @MartinSeysen I see. I know this example! Actually you can shrink your lattice to be unimodular and give a counterexample to my question for unimodular case as well...

Comment: Usually, you want the lengths of the vectors in a unimodular lattice to be integral. So shrinking (or expanding)  the 5-dimensional example won't do. I think that Niemeier lattices (of dimension 24) are counterexamples for the unimodular case, 
see Conway, Sloane, Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups.

Comment: @MartinSeysen Thanks! Now I am speculating a slightly weaker version of this might be true, please see my update.

Comment: @taylor It seems like your weaker version should easily follow from [Minkowski's second theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_second_theorem) (as you are assuming unimodularity).

Comment: @Mark I am a little confused... how is it related to the successive minima of a lattice?

Comment: @taylor I was thinking that you can show that there exists a basis of all norms bounded in a large enough ball, and one could then "work backwards" to argue for the existence of a primitive vector of your desired form.